# How can I triple boot Xubuntu, Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: boot, grub2

#### Triple Booting Xubuntu, Ubuntu and Windows

I'm an avid Xubuntu (Ubuntu + XFCE) user but I also dual boot with Windows XP.  I originally created 3 partitions and wanted to use the empty one as a storage volume but now I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (the one with Unity) to do advanced testing and packaging. Ideally I would love to keep these two totally separate as I had problems in the past with conflicts between Unity and XFCE.  This way I could wipe the Ubuntu w/ Unity installation if there are problems and really mess around with it.

My disk looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 200.0 GB, 200049647616 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 24321 cylinders, total 390721968 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    78139454    39069696    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        78141440   156280831    39069696   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       156282878   386533375   115125249    5  Extended
/dev/sda4       386533376   390721535     2094080   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5       156282880   386533375   115125248   83  Linux
```

Keep each in it's own partition and totally separate and be able to select from each of the three systems from the GRUB boot menu...

sda1 ---> [Windows XP]
sda2 ---> [Ubuntu 12.04] "Unity"
sda3(4,5) --> [Xubuntu 12.02] "Primary XFCE"

#### *What is the safest and easiest way to do this without messing my system up and requiring invasive activity?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your installation using the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS CD.

- When you reach the `Installation Type Page`, select `Something Else`.
- Now, you will get a page listing your partitions.
- Select `/dev/sda2` and select `Modify`
- Now, give the `Use as` as `ext4` and `mount point` as `/`
- You can just reuse your existing `swap` partition.
- Continue with the installation.

After the installation, you should be having a system that you desired.

Comment: Great. Happy to help.

Comment: In this question Windows XP and Xubuntu are already installed. In the general case it's preferable to install Windows first in a dual/triple boot system so it doesn't overwrite GRUB, then Xubuntu or Ubuntu can be installed in whatever order you please.